# No guarda datos de entrada a base de datos Mysql, error eclipselink

Tags: mysql, maven, wildfly, eclipselink

```
20:54:17,688 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36) [EL Warning]: 2020-08-25 20:54:17.686--ServerSession(1768869142)--PersistenceUnitInfo innovappTX has transactionType RESOURCE_LOCAL and therefore jtaDataSource will be ignored

20:54:17,690 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36) [EL Info]: 2020-08-25 20:54:17.69--ServerSession(1768869142)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070

20:54:18,320 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36) [EL Severe]: 2020-08-25 20:54:18.318--ServerSession(1768869142)--Local Exception Stack: 

20:54:18,321 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36) Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException

20:54:18,321 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36) Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/innmaestro

20:54:18,322 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36) Error Code: 0

20:54:18,322 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)

20:54:18,322 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:326)

20:54:18,323 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:138)

20:54:18,323 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)

20:54:18,323 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:204)

20:54:18,323 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:746)

20:54:18,324 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:253)

20:54:18,324 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:728)

20:54:18,324 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)

20:54:18,324 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:305)

20:54:18,325 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:337)

20:54:18,325 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:303)

20:54:18,325 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at com.innovapp.converter.LugarConverter.getAsObject(LugarConverter.java:25)

20:54:18,326 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.getConvertedValue(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:630)

20:54:18,326 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1045)

20:54:18,326 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:975)

20:54:18,327 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1248)

20:54:18,327 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)

20:54:18,327 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)

20:54:18,328 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)

20:54:18,328 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)

20:54:18,328 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)

20:54:18,328 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)

20:54:18,329 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)

20:54:18,329 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)

20:54:18,329 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)

20:54:18,329 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)

20:54:18,330 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)

20:54:18,330 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)

20:54:18,330 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)

20:54:18,330 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)

20:54:18,331 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)

20:54:18,331 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at com.innovapp.conf.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:58)

20:54:18,331 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)

20:54:18,332 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)

20:54:18,335 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)

20:54:18,336 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)

20:54:18,336 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)

20:54:18,336 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)

20:54:18,337 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

20:54:18,337 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)

20:54:18,337 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)

20:54:18,338 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

20:54:18,338 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)

20:54:18,339 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)

20:54:18,339 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)

20:54:18,339 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)

20:54:18,339 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)

20:54:18,340 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)

20:54:18,340 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

20:54:18,340 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)

20:54:18,340 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

20:54:18,341 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

20:54:18,341 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)

20:54:18,341 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)

20:54:18,341 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)

20:54:18,342 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)

20:54:18,342 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)

20:54:18,343 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)

20:54:18,343 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

20:54:18,343 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

20:54:18,343 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

20:54:18,343 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36) Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/innmaestro

20:54:18,344 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)

20:54:18,344 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)

20:54:18,344 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:98)

20:54:18,344 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36)   ... 59 more

20:54:18,345 INFO  [stdout] (default task-36) 

20:54:18,345 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-36) Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/innmaestro
Error Code: 0: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/innmaestro
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:303)
    at com.innovapp.converter.LugarConverter.getAsObject(LugarConverter.java:25)
    at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.getConvertedValue(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:630)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1045)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:975)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1248)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at com.innovapp.conf.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/innmaestro
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:746)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:728)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/innmaestro
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:98)
    ... 59 more

20:54:18,357 SEVERE [org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler] (default task-36) Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/innmaestro
Error Code: 0: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/innmaestro
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:303)
    at com.innovapp.converter.LugarConverter.getAsObject(LugarConverter.java:25)
    at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.getConvertedValue(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:630)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1045)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:975)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1248)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at com.innovapp.conf.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/innmaestro
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:746)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:728)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/innmaestro
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:98)
    ... 59 more

20:54:18,363 SEVERE [org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler] (default task-36) Could not handle exception!: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No default error page (Status 500 or java.lang.Throwable) and no error page for type "class javax.persistence.PersistenceException" defined!
    at org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler.handleRedirect(PrimeExceptionHandler.java:317)
    at org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler.handleAjaxException(PrimeExceptionHandler.java:157)
    at org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler.handle(PrimeExceptionHandler.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at com.innovapp.conf.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at
```

Comment: has añadido la libreria del mysql-conector?

Comment: el servidor esta encendido de mysql

Comment: si todo lo anterior esta bien.

Comment: puedes poner tu código para verlo

Comment: es algo robusto  para subirlo..

Comment: a lo mejor es esto que te acabo de poner

Comment: Estas usando algún gestor de paquetes como maven o gradle?

Comment: si señor Maven.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando uno recibe el error:

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:...

...esto quiere decir que el código JDBC es incapaz de encontrar el driver necesario para establecer la conexión a la base de datos MySQL.

Con las versiones modernas de Java, existe una sola explicación para este error: **que el conector .jar de MySQL no está en el classpath de la aplicación.**

En este caso, la solución es de simplemente ir a bajar el conector .jar [del sitio de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) y agregarlo al classpath de la aplicación.

---

**¿Ayuda agregar una llamada a `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")`?**

No, no cambia nada.

En versiones mucho mas antiguas de Java/JDBC, el error también podía suceder aunque el .jar estuviera en el classpath. Y en estos casos, en efecto se recomendaba de usar `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` para asegurarse de que la clase `Driver` estuviera cargada antes de tratar de establecer la conexión.

Pero a partir de Java 6/JDBC 4.0 (¡hace mas de 10 años ya!) se incluyeron cambios para que ya no fuera necesario llamar a `Class.forName`. Nota lo que la [documentación de `DriverManager` para Java 6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) dice (y claro, la documentación dice lo mismo para las versiones posteriores de Java):

> Applications no longer need to explictly load JDBC drivers using `Class.forName()`.

Traducción libre:

> Aplicaciones ya no necesitan cargar los JDBC drivers explicítamente usando `Class.forName()`.

Siendo que este ajuste se hizo hace más de 10 años ya, sería bueno que no siguieramos difundiendo esta idea obsoleta de que se debe llamar `Class.forName` en estas situaciones.

Comment: En variables de entorno se esta trabajando con jdk1.8.0.101 y wildfly 10 en este la conexión es exitosa, pero a la hora de llenar un formulario nunca llega a guardar en  la base de datos Mysql

Answer (score 0):

Listo ya esta solucionado,fue un error de configuración en persistence.xml
Solo fue configurar la url con ?serverTimezone=UTC problema de Zona horaria

[image: Solo fue configurar la url con ?serverTimezone=UTC problema de Zona horaria]

Comment: Ayudaría mas como respuesta que expusieras como corregiste esa mala configuración